# Need to open a readme.md file while nuget installation

Tags: nuget, markdown, nuget-package

Need to open the readme file while nuget is getting installated.Able to add the readme file which is added to the project through the dotnet pack. while unpacking the nugpkg file able to view the readme.md file. but readme.md file is getting opened when the nuget is installed.
Tried the same with readme.txt which worked perfectly and opened to readme.txt when nuget was installed.

```
'<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageReadmeFile>readme.md</PackageReadmeFile>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="readme.md" pack="true" PackagePath="." />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>'
```

the corresponding .csproj is packed and pushed to custom nuget gallery which is used by another project ,when installting the nuget need to open the readme.md file

Comment: You have to have `txt` extension, or Visual Studio will not show it. `md` extension will not work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#add-a-readme-and-other-files

Answer (score 1):

@Peska: as mentioned by you went forward with using the txt file with the nuget and also the markdown file for listing the details of the project in gitlab.Thanks